# django-tastypie - How to make manytomany through relationship

Tags: django, api, tastypie, django-orm

I'm working on a API for a project and I have a relationship Order/Products through OrderProducts like this:

In catalog/models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
```

In order/models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, verbose_name='Products', through='OrderProducts')
    ...

class OrderProducts(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    ...
```

Now, when I load an Order through the API I'd like to get the related Products as well, so I tried this (with django-tastypie):

In order/api.py

```
class OrderResource(ModelResource):
    products = fields.ToManyField('order.api.OrderProductsResource', products, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Order.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'order'

class OrderProductsRessource(ModelResource):
    order = fields.ToOneField(OrderResource, 'order')

    class Meta:
        queryset = OrderProducts.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'order/products'
```

which give me this error message: "'Product' object has no attribute 'order'". So I'm not sure what's wrong or missing, it probably requires something in my Product resource as well but I tried several way without success. Any help would be welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
order = fields.ToOneField(OrderResource, 'order')
```

The error is pretty straight-forward. `Product` really doesn't have an attribute named `order`. Your `OrderProduct` join table does, but your M2M doesn't return `OrderProduct`s it returns `Product`s.

Comment: I'm probably still missing something but I don't see what field the ToOneField is supposed to use or what the M2M is supposed to return ?

Comment: You need a `ProductResource` not an `OrderProductResource`. That's your problem. It's just like setting up the M2M on the model itself. You don't do `models.ManyToManyField(OrderProduct)`; you do `models.ManyToManyField(Product)`. It's the same here, you create your `ToManyField` with a link to a `ProductResource` that returns `Product`s.

Comment: Ok, got it ;) For some reasons, I thought I had to redefine the whole relationship within the API but it's smarter than that… Thanks for you help.

Comment: Hello @djevg were you able to solve this problem? Can you post your solution if that's the case. Thanks!